# Use Feedly without Pinterest

Tags: google-chrome, pinterest, feedly

When I use Feedly on Chrome, it keeps popping up Pinterest login dialogs. This happens when I click on Flickr photos within the Feedly view, and seemingly also at random intervals when scrolling past items in Feedly (using a Mac touchpad). Is this something that can be disabled?

Comment: What accounts do you have authenticated to your Feedly? Can you maybe add a screenshot?

Comment: Indeed. I'd like to just be able to access the regular Chrome context menu and save the image myself. Being **forced** to use a third-party is not user-friendly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Click "Prefs" in the upper left (just under your name)
2. In the preferences panel scroll to the "Sharing" section
3. Turn off Pintrest integration

[image]